# Редактор графического интерфейса для tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui

Существует ли какой-нибудь графический интерфейс для работы с tkinter, для  конкретики приведу пример

[image: Интерфейс Visual Basic]

В вышеприведенном примере можно было просто перетаскивать элементы, потом редактировать их на свой лад, и в конце-концов писать код в уже готовое пространство. Вопрос заключается в наличии подобного интерфейса для tkinter.